# Parsing XML in SQL Server 2005

Tags: xml, t-sql, parsing, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005, i am trying to parse below XML to details in following format, but i am unable to do it. Appreciate any help.
I want my select output like

```
1 TagSold Tag        0   101 2
2 TagReg  Customer   101 0   4
3 TagAdj  Tag        0   105 2



<TagDistributor>
<stbLedgerEntryTypes>
    <stbLedgerEntryType type="TagSold">
        <vcMapping>Tag</vcMapping>
        <tiCustTrxnTypeID>0</tiCustTrxnTypeID>
        <tiTagTrxnTypeID>101</tiTagTrxnTypeID>
        <tiPaymentTypeID>2</tiPaymentTypeID>
    </stbLedgerEntryType>
    <stbLedgerEntryType type="TagReg">
        <vcMapping>Customer</vcMapping>
        <tiCustTrxnTypeID>101</tiCustTrxnTypeID>
        <tiTagTrxnTypeID>0</tiTagTrxnTypeID>
        <tiPaymentTypeID>4</tiPaymentTypeID>
    </stbLedgerEntryType>
    <stbLedgerEntryType type="TagAdj">
        <vcMapping>Tag</vcMapping>
        <tiCustTrxnTypeID>0</tiCustTrxnTypeID>
        <tiTagTrxnTypeID>105</tiTagTrxnTypeID>
        <tiPaymentTypeID>2</tiPaymentTypeID>
    </stbLedgerEntryType>
</stbLedgerEntryTypes></TagDistributor>
```

I tried the follwing. I got the output. but in the first column i don't get the attribute value to diffrentiate. I have doubt in first line.

```
SELECT 
         a.b.query('.').value('@type', 'varchar(128)'),
         a.b.query('vcMapping').value('.', 'varchar(128)'),
         a.b.query('tiCustTrxnTypeID').value('.', 'int'),
         a.b.query('tiTagTrxnTypeID').value('.', 'int'),
         a.b.query('tiPaymentTypeID').value('.', 'int')
FROM    @ipv_xmlDistributorInfo.nodes('TagDistributor/stbLedgerEntryTypes/stbLedgerEntryType') a(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
   x.value('(@type)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Type',
   x.value('(vcMapping)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'vcMapping',
   x.value('(tiCustTrxnTypeID)[1]', 'int') AS 'tiCustTrxnTypeID',
   x.value('(tiTagTrxnTypeID)[1]', 'int') AS 'tiTagTrxnTypeID',
   x.value('(tiPaymentTypeID)[1]', 'int') AS 'tiPaymentTypeID'
FROM XMLTable x
CROSS APPLY x.myXMLField.nodes('/TagDistributor/stbLedgerEntryTypes/stbLedgerEntryType') 
  n(x)
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3557c/1).

Good luck.

Comment: If you need the ROW_NUMBER, then this should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3557c/3